# Google Spreadsheet - string value getting converted to date?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Guys i have a google sheet with `column taskName` and its type is `plain text`. If I enter any value like `5 jul` under this `column` it is stored as `5 jul`.

I add value in my sheet using a code similar to this:

```
        var name = "5 Jul";
        var url = "&taskName=" + encodeURIComponent(name);
        var encodedString = encodeReservedCharacters(url);


        var htmlVal = "<html><script src='" + url + "?action=addName&groupId=" + groupId + "&prefix=addNameCallback" + "&" + encodedString + "'><'/script><'/html>";

        $("#checkscript").html(htmlVal);

        function encodeReservedCharacters(queryString) {
            var reservedCharWithEquivalentHexCode = {
                "(": "%28",
                ")": "%29",
                "/": "%2F",
                "*": "%2A",
                "'": "%27"
            };
            queryString = queryString.replace(/[()/*']/g, function(match) {
                return reservedCharWithEquivalentHexCode[match];
            });
            return queryString;
        };
```

`groupId` is my worksheet id that i get using `OAuth` token
Sheet is updated but instead of `"5 Jul"`, `7/5/2015` is stored. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in Apps script or Java script? I tried to set the formatting in sheet(for a cell) to Plain text and tried this code: function formatTest(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("E18");
 range.clearFormat();
  sheet.getRange("E18").setValue("5 jul"); }. It actually saved it as '5jul'. Please check if this is useful.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had to prepend a tick (') to the cell contents that were suddenly interpreted as date by the new Google Sheets, such as `"2015-06"` (now I insert `"'2015-06"`)

Comment: Thats what i m doing but is there other way around